# How to set permissions so job runs from cron

Tags: permissions, scripts, cron

I have python script which runs fine.  I want to run it as a cron job every 10 minutes

I've done `crontab -e` and entered the line

```
*/10 * * * * root python /path/to/script/script.py
```

It doesn't seem to be running.

So I've played around on the command line and seeing at which point it stops running.  It runs in it's directory and every one preceeding it until I move out of my home directory (ie if I'm in `/home/henry/` then it runs but if I'm in, for example, `/var` then it doesn't) when I get a permission error trying to write to a file.

```
# save this for next time
with open(mycsvfile, "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows([s.strip().encode("utf-8") for s in row ]for row in list_of_rows)
outfile.close()
```

I've already done `chmod +x /home/user/Location/Of/Script` to ensure the script has access (I thought).  What am I missing?  Thanks for your help

Comment: "*/10 * * * * root python /path/to/script/script.py" is for /etc/crontab not crontab -e.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the string `root` (assuming `python` exists in the `cron` defined `PATH`, otherwise use absolute path e.g. `/usr/bin/python`):

```
*/10 * * * * python /path/to/script/script.py
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/script/script.py
```

**Why:**

- When you use `crontab -e` to open a cron table, you are opening the invoking user's `crontab`, no username field is allowed (unlike  `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d/*`)
- As it stands now, you are running the command `root` (which presumably is not available) with the arguments `python` and `/path/to/script/script.py`

Also if you have made the script executable, you should add a shebang indicating the script interpreter (e.g. `/usr/bin/python`) instead of running the script as an argument to the interpreter. Then you can do:

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/script/script.py
```

Comment: It has the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python`.  Does that mean I can remove the `usr/bin/python` ?

Comment: @HenryM Yes....

Comment: but it still isn't running?

Comment: @HenryM Make sure the script is executable. If it does not run still,  1)Check `/var/log/syslog` for `cron` entries 2)set the job as `*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/script/script.py >/tmp/cron_log 2>&1`, and then check the content of `/tmp/cron_log` after run.

Comment: my syslog has the following two lines everytime it runs.  `(henry) CMD (/home/henry/Documents/Scraper/clint.py)
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`.  The first is the script and the 2nd is because I do not have a mail server installed.  But the output file the job is writing to isn't being updated.

Comment: So I've changed the line to include the python path and it now seems to be running because I get `(henry) CMD (/usr/bin/python /home/henry/Documents/Scraper/clint.py)` but my output files are still not being updated.  This brings me back to my original question about permissions of output files

Comment: @HenryM This seems very much like a problem of your script. Do `*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/script/script.py >/tmp/cron_log 2>&1` and check the file `/tmp/cron_log` like i mentioned earlier.

Comment: it is coming out empty

Comment: @HenryM Make an identical environment and run the script from terminal from the environment. As far as the `cron` is concerned your primary problem is solved already.

Comment: Sorry, I've worked it out.  It is writing the files just not in the directory I expected.  I've found them.  Really sorry and thank you